# Iframe in Chrome error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window'

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

No clue how to go further on this...when all I did was `
Works in Firefox, not in Chrome.
Could be something related to http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/questions/6299203-javascript-errors-in-chrome-

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had the same problem with *localStorage*, and fixed it like this :

Under **Settings > Privacy > Content settings**, change the cookies' settings to **"Allow local data to be set"** or the second option (in my case, it was previously on *"Block sites from setting any data"*).

[image: image of chrome settings -> content settings -> allow local data to be set (recommended) checked]

On newer Chrome versions, make sure the first option is ticked here: chrome://settings/content/cookies

Comment: +1 Thanks, this helped us with an issue we were having elsewhere, this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: @Loktar Even if my screenshot clearly lacks of freehand circles, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: This fixed it, thank you, but **this iFrame has been working for years unchanged**. It's on my site; the iFrame reads a remote site. What could cause it to break? Did the remote server make some change? Is this option usually off in Chrome, and I somehow turned it on? I'm worried the site will break for my users and I'd like to understand what caused it.

Comment: Do you guys know why this issue came up abruptly? It was working fine earlier.

Comment: This answer is for users. We here at Stackoverflow are developers. The question is how to solve this restriction at website developer side.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber AFAIK, as a developer, you just can't. If you have a way to bypass user's permissions to set local data (which sounds like a bad idea IMO), you're welcome to share it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but my problem was a script blocking plug-in *ScriptBlock* that I had set to allow the site but was still blocking some actions and not reporting it.

Disabled the script blocker and voila!

Answer (score 2):

For the latest chrome browser, this might work and better guide for you. And it works for me.

`Settings` > `Privacy and security` > `Cookies and other site data` > `Allow all cookies`

That should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to block most 3rd party cookies, you can add an exemption. I usually can do it through the cookie button that pops up in the AddressBar, but it wouldn't let me for localhost. I had to add it via chrome://settings/content/cookies [Picture of chrome://settings/content/cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAdRR.png)