# Iframe in Chrome error: Failed to read 'localStorage' from 'Window': Access denied for this document

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, ember.js, ember-cli, content-security-policy

I have a web app which uses localStorage. Now we want to embed this web app on other (third-party) sites via iframe. We want to provide an iframe embed similar to youtube so that other websites can embed our web app in an iframe. Functionally it is the same as if it wouldn't be embedded. But it does not work. Chrome prints the error message:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

I just do the following check (in the iframe):

```js
if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
    // SETUP SESSION, AUHT, LOCALE, SETTINGS ETC
} else {
    // PROVIDE FEEDBACK TO THE USER
}
```

I checked my security settings in Chrome like described in [another Stackoverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456891/iframe-in-chrome-error-uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-sessionstora)  but it doesn't work. Is there any change to make embedding possible without the need of adjusting (default) security settings of most modern browsers?

To give more information, we use Ember-CLI for our web app and turned on [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) ([more info about the Ember-CLI CSP](http://www.ember-cli.com/#content-security-policy)). Could CSP cause our web app to throw security errors?

Comment: your title mentions an `iframe`? is something in the iframe trying to access the local storage?  that sounds like it could trigger a security warning?

Comment: @Grapho: I rephrased my initial question. We just want to provide other websites the possibility to embed our web app via `iframe`. So the `window.localStorage` call is in our web app code and therefore in the `iframe`. We don't want to do any fancy cross domain thing. Just make our web app available via iframe. Hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: if the web app uses local storage, then running it in an iframe _will_ cause a cross-domain issue, because Window is global... it will be trying to access the local client's window.localstorage.. remember locastorage is a client browser thing.. not a hosted/server thing.. your app has no knowledge if it is being served from anywhere

Comment: So there is no chance to get it working? We didn't design our app for this but many customers requested this feature, therefore we need some solution. I know that localStorage is no server thing. But I thought the entries are stored by domain. I don't want to set anything for another domain, just for the domain which is specified in the src attribute of the iframe. Is there a way to bypass the window and just write to our "domain-entry" of the localStorage?

Comment: not with localStorage.  if you want to only store things on your domain, you will need a back-end to persist data to... utilizing ember-data or such.

Comment: Maybe use a localstorage polyfill. Might help. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357625

Comment: @blessenm a pollyfill could work  if the issue lies soley in that the client has no localstorage capability.. however the end result would still be that clients would be storing data on their own local browsers... which becomes a problem if the data is needed to be passed back and forth through the iframe

Comment: Maybe a polyfill is a good solution. Concerning our usage of localStorage: we don't store data we want to persist to our back-end there. We just save settings like actual locale, actual access token etc. If the user clears the localStorage it's totally fine she/he just needs to set locale again and login again. We use [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/) which relies on localStorage. I hope it's not too painful to integrate a polyfill or something similar...

Comment: yet, data that is stored locally will not be available for the app hosted in the iframe.. which is why you are getting the original errors you posed.. not being able to read properties from the local storage

Comment: okay I see. So a user can not login to our app if it is hosted in an iframe, because I can't write login credentials to the localStorage. Hm... that's not good. Any idea how to fix this? Is the polyfill the only viable option?

Comment: the only thing i can suggest is looking into CSP: http://content-security-policy.com/  there should be a way to monkey with it to allow cross-origin cmmunication on iframes.. (see: sandbox).. however the disclaimer is that it is risky and could open up vulnerabilities...

Comment: also.. you could consider storing session info in a controller or service instead of local storage... only use local storage as a back up if user hits refresh.

Comment: I haven't had time to investigate into this issue more. I just tried it again and didn't embed the iframe in a html file which is serve from file-system. Instead I used a file served from a webserver. Magically everything works now (tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Safari). Maybe I explained my question not in the right way, but it seems to work as I expected when I first tried it.

Comment: So, your problem was solved just by serving the embedded iframe from a web server instead of directly from the file system?

Answer (score 72):

Under Chrome's Settings > Privacy > Content Settings, you have the cookie setting set to "Block sites from setting any data".

This checkbox is what is causing the exception.

Comment: if it's not default, it's mostly unusable, because users won't change settings to use some website.

Comment: It is not about the "Block sites from setting any data" option but rather: "Block third-party cookies and site data" setting which doesn't make most sites unusable, but cuts off most of the your-searches-related adverts

Comment: Seems quite unreasonable to expect visitors to adjust their settings for this. And I'm sure there has to be a better solution. I run into this problem trying to use the Youtube API on a site. Youtube works fine on other sites without changing any settings. There must be a better solution, or Youtube wouldn't work on other sites.

Comment: somehow the site was block in the content settings I might have had done it before. After remove the site from the blocking list it works just fine for me.

Comment: We are loading a react app in Iframe, In Mac + Chrome, Getting this error. We cannot tell customers to use the above to fix the error.  Is there any way in Javascript?

Comment: I was testing my site with incognito when I noticed that certain features break. Seems like Chrome's incognito blocks `localStorage` use within iframes by default now (there's a toggle for "Block third-party cookies" when you open up a fresh incognito page).

Comment: @joe did you find a solution for this? I need to be able to use the localstorage with iframe even when the "Block third-party cookies" option is enabled.

Comment: any new information?

Answer (score 29):

[According to this](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

> This exception is thrown when the "Block third-party cookies and site data" checkbox is set in Content Settings.
>   To find the setting, open Chrome settings, type "third" in the search box, click the Content Settings button, and view the fourth item under Cookies.

[image]

Comment: If going in this direction, use Manage Exceptions additional configuration section rather than unchecking this feature off

Answer (score 24):

On the following URL: `chrome://settings/content/cookies` uncheck "Block third-party cookies".

Comment: New URL: chrome://settings/cookies . You can also just search in the settings for "cookies". chrome://settings/?search=cookies

Answer (score 21):

If you're using **incognito mode**, make sure you **turn off** `"Block third-party cookies"`.

Open a new tab in any incognito window, and turn off the option:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

`localStorage` is per domain, per protocol. If you are trying to access `localStorage` from a standalone file, i.e. with `file:///` protocol, there is no domain per se. Hence browsers currently would complain that your document does not have access to `localStorage`. If you put your file in a web server (e.g. deploy in Tomcat) and access it from `localhost`, you will be able to access `localStorage`.

Comment: my self I had the issue with an iFrame today inside a website .. hence your answer is missing something :/ still reading about it I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: if I read comment on the question it makes complete sense : if the web app uses local storage, then running it in an iframe will cause a cross-domain issue, because Window is global... it will be trying to access the local client's window.localstorage.. remember locastorage is a client browser thing.. not a hosted/server thing.. your app has no knowledge if it is being served from anywhere

Answer (score 5):

I checked all the answers but ended up not finding anything.  Then I realized what browser I'm using.  If you're using Brave (Chromium Based), you will get this error if your shield is up.  Try lowering your shield.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If disable block third-party cookies is not an option, you can use try...catch:

```
try {
 // SETUP SESSION, AUHT, LOCALE, SETTINGS ETC
} catch(err) {
 // PROVIDE FEEDBACK TO THE USER
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A more secure way of doing this in Chrome would be to allow only the site(s) that you trust:

```
Chrome
  -> "Settings"
    -> "Show advanced settings..."
      -> "Privacy"
        -> "Content settings..."
          -> "Manage exceptions..."
            -> (add a pattern such as [*.]microsoft.com)
            -> be sure to hit enter
            -> "Done"
          -> "Done"
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem in my phone, I couldn't open a certain site with chrome.
It took me some time to find the cookies on my phone, when I found it, I saw that  my cookies was blocked.

go to your Settings  --> Site settings --> Cookies

and allow the site to save and read cookie data, **make sure that you don't block third-party cookies!**
[image: cookies in chrome browser on phone]

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the comments, localstorage is single origin only -- the origin of the page.  Attempting to access the page's localstorage from an iframe loaded from a different origin will result in an error.

The best you can do is hack it with XDM via the postMessage API. [This library](https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage) purports to do the heavy lifting for you, but I haven't tried it. However, I would make sure you're aware of [IE's terrible support for XDM](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) before going down this route.

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment before, everything works as expected after I embedded the iframe in a file which is served from a webserver instead from file system. So everything works fine. Maybe I just phrased my question wrongly. But thanks for all the comments and explanations. If someone is interested in more details, just ask :)

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Can you let me know how you solved it?

Comment: same problem here, thinking about cookies.. :/

Answer (score 1):

imho it has nothing to do with CSP settings on your ember cli app but to do with browser settings.
Some browsers (Chrome) block localStorage content loaded into an iframe.
We too are facing a similar situation for our Ember App,were we have an ember app and a plugin which loads on 3rd party websites, the user token loaded into the iframe gets blocked in Chrom,we are experimenting with some solutions, will keep this thread posted as to how it goes.

Comment: any update on this one?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this warning - under Chrome's Settings -> Privacy -> Content settings, you have to clear the "Block third-party cookies and site data" option

Answer (score 0):

Secure way of doing this in Chrome top right, click on eye logo and allow the site you are on to use third-party cookies:

[Check this image if you can't find the eye logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89pHF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Clear Cookie

Chrome->setting->privacy and Policy->Sites that can never use cookies  In  turnremove cookie for local storage.

Answer (score 0):

For all others like me who search for a Javascript solution/fix:

```
var storageSupported = false;

try
{ 
    storageSupported = (window.localStorage && true);
}
catch (e) {}

if (storageSupported) 
{ 
    // your code
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that Chrome 113 and Chrome mobile 120 incognito seem to "Block third-party cookies and site data" while the latest Desktop version (120) only blocks "third-party cookies".

The difference was: only the former affects localStorage access. Looks like the issue should not happen anymore.