# localStorage null when being embedded in another domain

Tags: javascript, local-storage, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

**My intention:** Facilitate localStorage value transfer from one domain to another

I have a page, **domain.com/storage-agent.html** which will be embedded in an iframe by **diffdomain.com**. **domain.com/storage-agent.html** has the following response header.

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://diffdomain.com https://diff.domain.com
```

(`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` also exists, but anyway, it'll be ignored by Chrome in favour of `frame-ancestors`.)

**domain.com/storage-agent.html** has a script, that will `postMessage` a value from localStorage (of **domain.com**) and the host/embedder listens to it.

The problem is, when the aforementioned script accesses `localStorage.getItem('key')` when it's embedded by **diffdomain.com** in an iframe, it's null. `JSON.stringify(localStorage)` is `{}` too, meaning none of the values are available.

But, if I load **domain.com/storage-agent.html** in a separate tab and do the same `localStorage.getItem('key')` in console, I get the value as expected.

If I embed **domain.com/storage-agent.html** in **diff.domain.com**, then also things work as expected. So nothing wrong with the script that gets from localStorage.

Can't get my head around what's happening.

Comment: `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors`  is just defining to what ancestors an `iframe` may be embedded. That doesn't mean the two sites can access each other's local storage. The local storage in the browser is per domain and if the domain differs, you cannot access the local storage. It works for `example.com` and `api.example.com` because they are under the same domain. But it doesn't work for `example.com` and `anotherexample.com` because that are different domains

Comment: I'm not looking to access cross domain localStorage. I'm accessing domain.com's localStorage from a page in domain.com and looking to `postMessage` the result to the embedder. The only thing to note is, the domain.com page is embedded in an iframe by diffdomain.com.

Comment: Guess what? There's an undocumented behaviour (at least in Chromium, Safari & Firefox) - if third-party **cookie**s are blocked, the rule is applied to **localStorage** as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481516/iframe-in-chrome-error-failed-to-read-localstorage-from-window-access-deni. But for some reason, I didn't get this exception either.