# Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Tags: javascript, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    event.preventDefault();
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later
    deferredPrompt = event;
    // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
    var storageType = checkStoringCapabilities();
    if (storageType && storageType.getItem('installPromptDismissed') !== 'true') display_install_button();
});
```

```
function checkStoringCapabilities()
{
    var storage = false;
    if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined')
    {
        storage = localStorage;
    }
    else if (typeof window.sessionStorage !== 'undefined')
    {
        storage = sessionStorage;
    }
    return storage;
}
```

Only in prod environment, In sentry i get this error :
SecurityError : Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

This happen on android version 10, more than 200 event all coming from os:android 10 Model:K but also 2 from os:linux

sentry highlight this portion of code
`{snip} llprompt",t=>{t.preventDefault(),deferredPrompt=t,"true"!==localStorage.getItem("installPromptDismissed")&&display_install_button()});const  {snip}`

Tried to mimic android 10 from devtools, tried my android phone too (which has 10), no luck.

Comment: The general reason for this error is explained here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30481516/1427878 - but I am not sure, if the necessary setting to change, is available in the Android mobile browser(s).