# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. in iframe wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-masking

I have a website made with wordpress as a subdomain, but i want to mask the URL. I used the frame tag but the website doesn't load. I have tried it in Several Browsers but all throw same error.`

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
> at https://zbhqv2twq6gzat8fqu6klxmw.filmtilm.in/:1:91
> (index):273 [LiteSpeed] Start Lazy Load Images
> (index):273 Object
> (index):273 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
> at https://zbhqv2twq6gzat8fqu6klxmw.filmtilm.in/:273:8973
> /favicon.ico:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> (index):273 [LiteSpeed] Start Load JS Delayed
> (index):273 [LiteSpeed] Load  <script type=​"litespeed/​javascript">​…​​
> (index):273 [LiteSpeed] Load  <script type=​"litespeed/​javascript" data-src=​"https:​/​/​zbhqv2twq6gzat8fqu6klxmw.filmtilm.in/​wp-includes/​js/​jquery/​jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0" id=​"jquery-core-js">​​
> (index):273 [LiteSpeed] Load  <script data-optimized=​"1" type=​"litespeed/​javascript" data-src=​"https:​/​/​zbhqv2twq6gzat8fqu6klxmw.filmtilm.in/​wp-content/​litespeed/​js/​54df413b31a24ddc9a7d212e8f1aacbd.js?ver=76851">​​
> zbhqv2twq6gzat8fqu6klxmw.filmtilm.in/wp-content/litespeed/js/54df413b31a24ddc9a7d212e8f1aacbd.js?ver=76851:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Is there any way to resolve the error?
I am Having a VPS for the Hosting where i will be migrating this website. Attached the Image with the Hyperlink.[Website URL and Console for error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3z2W.png)

Comment: Related: [Iframe in Chrome error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456891/iframe-in-chrome-error-uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-sessionstora)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it just for yourself - then **allow all cookies for your domain**, but if you want to know, how to give access globally for users - I also want to know how. (have not found)