# Playwright - need to set session storage but getting access denied

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

Using both playwright and it's test runne to test a Angular app, I have a test scenario where I need to set the session storage. This is not for authentication, it is to test some logic that grabs from session storage.

I have the below, but I am getting access denied. How can I set the session storage in playwright for a test?

Note: I only need it on this single test, not the whole test suite.

> Error: page.evaluate: DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

```js
        const data = { ssoUser : { userId: 'abc' } };
        await page.evaluate(() => {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem('USER.SSO', JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

Comment: Related: [Iframe in Chrome error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456891/iframe-in-chrome-error-uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-sessionstora)

Comment: I don't believe I can set google chrome settings in playwright config

Comment: You can [set Chrome browser launch flags](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-option-args), though, so hopefully there's a flag for this. I don't see any offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Session storage is specific to a particular page or tab within a browser.
We may need to create a page session for that.
So did you access a page before trying to set the `sessionStorage`?

```
  // Access a page first
  await page.goto(`/`);

  const data = { ssoUser : { userId: 'abc' } };
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('USER.SSO', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```